# How to remove name while including image in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, sweave, r

I am including an image in R and found the name of the image file appearing with the image:

```
  name<-c("A.pdf","B.pdf","C.pdf","D.pdf")
  <<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
  for (i in 1:4)
  {      
     cat(paste("\\includegraphics[trim=0cm 10cm 0cm 5cm, clip=true,%
                          width=.7\\linewidth]{pdf_repository/",name[i],".pdf}",sep=""),"\n")
  }
  @
```

I found the names of image files: `A.pdf`, `B.pdf`, `C.pdf`, `D.pdf` also appear with the images. How can I remove them?

Comment: Why do you append the `pdf` suffix in line 5 again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `names` is outside a code block and so is being included as text to be formatted by LaTeX. Is that what you are seeing?  Moving it inside the R code block, I don't see file names.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
name<-c("A.pdf","B.pdf","C.pdf","D.pdf")
for (i in 1:4) {
  cat(paste("\\includegraphics[trim=0cm 10cm 0cm 5cm, clip=true, width=.7\\linewidth]{pdf_repository/",name[i],"}",sep=""),"\n")
}
@

\end{document}
```

gives the `.tex` file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[trim=0cm 10cm 0cm 5cm, clip=true, width=.7\linewidth]{pdf_repository/A.pdf} 
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 10cm 0cm 5cm, clip=true, width=.7\linewidth]{pdf_repository/B.pdf} 
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 10cm 0cm 5cm, clip=true, width=.7\linewidth]{pdf_repository/C.pdf} 
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 10cm 0cm 5cm, clip=true, width=.7\linewidth]{pdf_repository/D.pdf} 
\end{document}
```

which compiles to a PDF with just the 4 graphics (assuming there are the 4 PDFs to include in the given directory).

Answer (score 3):

As the first comment said, you wrote `.pdf` twice (e.g. in your tex output, you will see `A.pdf.pdf`).

As much as [I hate](http://yihui.name/en/2012/06/enjoyable-reproducible-research/) the `cat('\\includegraphics')` trick, here is the [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(fig.path = 'pdf_repository/')
@

\begin{document}
<<test, out.width='.7\\linewidth', out.extra='trim = 0cm 10cm 0cm 5cm, clip = true'>>=
plot(rnorm(30))
plot(rnorm(30))
plot(rnorm(30))
plot(rnorm(30))
@
\end{document}
```

Just like you call `Sweave()` on the Rnw file, you can install the `knitr` package and call `library(knitr); knit()`. You will never worry about multiple plots per chunk again.

[image: multiple plots from knitr]